# unique button jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I would like to have three (or more) normal buttons, that I would use underneath three pictures, only one would have a text "default" the other buttons would have the text "set as default" .

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Default" > 

<input type="button"id="button2"  value="Set as default" > 

<input type="button" id="button3"  value="Set as default" >
```

When "set as default" is clicked this button's text should change to default and also the color should change..(the previous button that was default will now be "set as default")

1. How do i do this using jquery for more than two buttons?
2. When i post this to php how will i know which one was the default?
3. If you have any other suggestions /code examples instead of buttons to select the
   default picture they are more than welcome

Comment: 3) how about radiobuttons with correspondent labels? but i guess thats kinda old stuff

Comment: Radio buttons are certainly what you need here. name attribute will let you know which was selected. jQueryUI has a nice buttonset for radio buttons that you may be interested in: http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Comment: it will get really funny as soon as you go for a dynamic generation of the amount of items selectable ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
  $('input[type="button"]').val('Set as default');
  $(this).val('Default');
});
```

PHP will know by giving them names: (button1, 2, 3) - the value will be "Default"

```
<input type="button" id="button1" name="button1" value="Default" > 

<input type="button"id="button2"  name="button2"  value="Set as default" > 

<input type="button" id="button3"  name="button3"  value="Set as default" >
```

Comment: make sure using jquery though

Answer (score 1):

1) You can combine selectors with a comma.

```
$("#button1, #button2, #button3").on("click", function(){
  $("#button1, #button2, #button3").val("Set as default");
  $(this).val("Default");
});
```

2) You could add a hidden input to capture whatever you need (`<input type='hidden' id='selectedbutton'>`).

```
$("#button1, #button2, #button3").on("click", function(){
  $("#button1, #button2, #button3").val("Set as default");
  $(this).val("Default");
  $("#selectedbutton").val($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

3) Radio buttons are a nice option as they enforce just one is selected and also work to inform your server. You will still need to change text manually (unless you want to get fancy with CSS).

ETA: You mention wanting to control colors and perhaps other styles. I would recommand you make better use of classes for both formatting and selecting:

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class='btn-set-default btn-is-default' value="Default" > 
<input type="button"id="button2" class='btn-set-default' value="Set as default" >    
<input type="button" id="button3" class='btn-set-default' value="Set as default" >
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".btn-set-default").on("click", function(){
  $(".btn-set-default").removeClass("btn-is-default").val("Set as default");
  $(this).addClass("btn-is-default").val("Default");
  $("#selectedbutton").val($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

CSS

```
.btn-set-default { }
.btn-is-default { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
$(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(){
      $(":button").prop('value','Set as default');
        $(this).prop('value', 'Default'); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDkqL/

The one that gets posted with value "Default" is the one that was clicked.